# Create a pop-up message in Google Sheets for users with view-only access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am working with this script:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('This is my pop up message!');
}
```

Simple, except it only shows up for collaborators. What do I need to add to it or my spreadsheet to have people with view-only access to the spreadsheet see it as well?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80245/176185

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onOpen trigger for view-only users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661868/onopen-trigger-for-view-only-users)

Comment: See the documentation on triggers - both [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) and [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) - and note the restriction: **They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode.**