# App Script for google doc not working for user without editor permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Our team has a Google Doc template that we must clone and edit as part of our process. To make this a bit simpler, I wanted to add a "Clone" menu using App Script. This would call a function that clone the document and perform some simple replacement of names and dates, etc.

```
function onOpen() {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Actions')
        .addItem("Clone", "clone_and_fill_basic_info")
        .addToUi();
}
```

The script works. But I found that users who only have "Commenter" access (which is the entire organization) does not see the new menu item. Now this clones the original doc, but does not change the original doc.  User also report that once they make a their own copy of the doc (of which they are the sole editor), the menu shows up. So it clearly is an access issue.

I searched for any relevant permission related setting in the project and did not find any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onOpen trigger for view-only users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661868/onopen-trigger-for-view-only-users)